# wondering how to know symbol in Time Profiler of Instruments with only address displayed in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, instruments, profiler

I am very new to Instruments and have been trying to resolve an issue with my app that causes my collectionView to scroll very slowly.  I have run the Time Profiler and repeated the scroll function many times.  Below is the screen shot from Instruments.  I am wondering how I can find out what are the symbols or methods associated with the lines that just show a memory address.  Of particular concern for me is the highlighted initial line.  If anybody can help me understand this or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Insturments.app, select “Symbols…” in the “File” menu.
2. Select the binary that is missing symbols in the left panel
3. Push the “Locate”-button next to the text “dSYM Path:”
4. Browse to the location of the dSYM-file and select it.
5. Push the “Done”-button

To find the dSYM for your binary, you can right-click on your app in the ”Products”-folder in Xcode.

It was described in the Instruments documentation at 
[Restoring Symbols When an Instruments Trace Shows Only Addresses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is no longer useful, as the document no longer exists at the link supplied. This is precisely why links should be substantiated with a summary of the information they provide.